# Не работает цикл telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Бот получает цифру 1 2 или 3, это значение, сколько нужно ссылок но бот отправляет сообщение отправьте ссылку 2 или 3 раза и записывает только последний результат

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda x: True)
def yt_url(message):
    if message.text != "Выбери кол-во":
        l = message.text
        for i in range(int(l)):
            bot.send_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, text = "Отправьте ссылку")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, save1)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А бот записывает куда?

Comment: Как бот должен понять, что, куда, какие ссылки и сколько раз отправлять, если в Вашем коде этого нет?